# Terms and condition is not working on checkout page?

Tags: error, terms-and-conditions

I have enabled terms and condition from admin panel

**Steps**

1. Navigate to `System => Configuration => Sales => Checkout => Checkout Options`
2. Set **‘Enable Terms and Conditions’ to ‘Yes’**

**Next**

1. Created terms and condition
2. Navigate to Sales => Terms and Conditions
3. **Status (required): select ‘Enabled’.**
4. But in front end  T&C not working. it's disabled

[image]

Frontend HTML below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" title="terms and condition" value="1" name="agreement[1]" id="agreement-1" disabled="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: please help me?

Comment: Try falling back to base theme to see if this is some theme related bug